# Add a CSS class to single code chunks in RMarkdown

Tags: css, r, knitr, r-markdown

Is it possible to add a CSS class to a certain code chunk?

Assume the following file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---


```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

I want to give the chunk labeled 'cars' a certain CSS class, e.g. `.myClass`.
Is there any possibility like

````
```{r cars} {.myClass}
summary(cars)
```
````

or so? I am aware of hacks like wrapping the whole chunk in another `<div>`. I am interested in a straight forward solution.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Edit: this feature was introduced in knitr v.1.16 (05/18/17)**
`class.source` and `class.output` options apply additional HTML classes to source and output chunks (see [knitr documentation](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/)).
To add `myClass` to source chunk:

````
```{r cars, class.source='myClass'}
summary(cars)
```
````

---

**Previous answer that inspired the `class.source` options (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030477/changing-chunk-background-color-in-rmarkdown))**
You can add a class using the `fenced_code_attributes` pandoc's extension (which is intended to add attributes to the `<pre>` tag, see [here](http://pandoc.org/README.html#fenced-code-blocks)) and a `knitr` [output hook](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#output_hooks).

The following example works fine:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
  output: 
    html_document:
      md_extensions: +fenced_code_attributes
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  return(paste0(
    "```{.r",
    ifelse(is.null(options$class),
      "", 
      paste0(" .", gsub(" ", " .", options$class))
    ),
    "}\n",
    x,
    "\n```"
  ))
})
```

```{r cars, class="myClass1 myClass2"}
summary(cars)
```
````

After knitting this `.Rmd` file, the `HTML` document looks like this:

```
<pre class="r myClass1 myClass2">
    <code>
        summary(cars)
    </code>
</pre>
```

*The `fenced_code_attributes` extension is enabled by default: in standard cases, you don't need to include the line `md_extensions: +fenced_code_attributes` in your `YAML` header.*

I don't know if there's more straightforward solution using `knitr`.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that the class is added to the img output from the code chunk? Or can I add the to the <img> in another way?