# Chunk option class.output is not working on Error Message

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, chunks, bookdown

I am preparing a tutorial for a course and I want to change the colour of the error to be red. I am using BookDown and gitbook as my output format. But I found that the option `class.output` is not working. I want to add a class to the output for the error message I get. How can I do that? You can use this as an example:

````
---
title: "Test Book"
author: "therimalaya"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
---

# Hello World

```{r, error = TRUE, class.output="red"}
rnorm(-10)
```
````

This works if there is no error.

Comment: Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 6):

`class.output` is not applied to errors (see [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#output-hooks)).
Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944197/add-a-css-class-to-single-code-chunks-in-rmarkdown/38168021#38168021), I suggest you to use an error hook:

````
```{r error-hook, echo=FALSE}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(error = function(x, options) {
  paste0(
    "```{", 
    ifelse(is.null(options$class.error), 
           "", 
           paste0(" .", gsub(" ", " .", options$class.error))
    ),
    "}\n",
    x,
    "\n```"
  )
})
```
````

Now, you can use a "new" `class.error` option in your chunk.

````
```{r, error = TRUE, class.error="red"}
rnorm(-10)
```
````

Feel free to open a feature request [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues).

Answer (score 2):

The ability to use custom CSS classes for errors, warnings, and messages was [just added to knitr](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1676), so you will be able to use the following syntax.

````
```{r error = TRUE, class.error = "bg-danger text-danger"}
rnorm(-10)
```
````

Here I'm using [Bootstrap classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-backgrounds), but you can pass any class(es) you need to `class.error`. The chunk options `class.message` and `class.warning` also work. Note that `class.output` is applied only to standard code outputs.

Comment: I see,there has quite some classes, thanks a lot...