# Is there a way to use knitr's css class options when using kable tables?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I recently read about knitr's css classes for chunks as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944197/add-a-css-class-to-single-code-chunks-in-rmarkdown) and [this example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/116-html-class.Rmd).

In general, this seems to work great. The trouble I'm having is that these options no longer seem to work if the output you're using is a kable. The example below illustrates what I'm talking about. In the first two chunks, I'm able to successfully add the css class `bg-success` to my output, but the third chunk does not apply this.

Inspecting the output html file, I find that the first two chunks are wrapped in `<pre class='bg-success'>...</pre>` html blocks while the third chunk is wrapped in a `<table class=table table-condensed>...</table>` html block. The `bg-success` class isn't picked up anywhere here.

Has anybody gotten knitr's class.output options to work with kable outputs? Is there a clean way to do this? I know that I could wrap the code chunk in divs and apply the class there, but that's messy and I would prefer to do this cleanly if possible.

````
---
title: "My Test"
output: html_document
---


\```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    message = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE)
\```

Class works when applied to text:

\```{r working, class.output='bg-success'}
paste("Normal", "R chunk", "output!!")
\```

Class works when applied to data frame:

\```{r working_table, class.output='bg-success'}
head(iris)
\```

Class does not work when applied to kable output:

\```{r not_working, class.output='bg-success'}
kable(head(iris))
\```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class `bg-success` to the table thru the `table.attr` argument:

```
knitr::kable(head(iris), table.attr = "class=\'bg-success\'") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling()
```

I realized that you need to modify the style of HTML table, passing class/argument to `kable_styling` [function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kableExtra/versions/1.1.0/topics/kable_styling).
Apparently, there is no need to specify `format` argument:

```
knitr::kable(head(iris), table.attr = "class=\'bg-success\'", format = "html") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling()
```

Also, you need to include `library(kableExtra)` to `{r setup}`.

You may find more info about `table.attr` argument at section [13.1.11 Customize HTML tables](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html)