# How to keep default R markdown colors when knitting to html?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

In R markdown or R studio, for a line like this

```
library('tidyverse')
```

`library` is colored in blue and `tidyverse` in green. When I knit to html, they appear in dark red and red respectively. How can I knit my html keeping the original color for the whole document? In the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/font-color.html), it says that I can use a `span tag` and set the color, but that seems to work for a specific code chunk. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030477/changing-chunk-background-color-in-rmarkdown) for the background color, not the text. Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944197/add-a-css-class-to-single-code-chunks-in-rmarkdown), but for single code chunks again. I believe it comes from the fact that colours have different names in R and HTML?  Is there a way to specify this in the `<style type="text/css">` section just below the YAML header? I code in R but I am totally new to CSS or HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `highlight: textmate` in the YAML header.

For instance,

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  html_document:
    highlight: textmate
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Test

```{r}
library("tidyverse")
```
````

knits to

[image: result]

##### Further reading

[R Markdown: The Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#appearance-and-style)